# Sending email from a java stateless EJB (Java EE-6)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email ussing an EJB but i the only thing i get in return in this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
```

This is how my EJB looks like:

```
@Stateless(name = "ejbs/EmailServiceEJB")
public class EmailServiceEJB extends Authenticator implements IEmailServiceEJB {

public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            "xxxxxxx");
}

public void sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(String destinationEmail,
        String name) {
    // OUR EMAIL SETTINGS
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";// Gmail
    int port = 465;
    String serviceUsername = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    String servicePassword = "xxxxxxx";// Our Gmail password

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", serviceUsername);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    // Destination of the email
    String to = destinationEmail;
    String from = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";

    // Creating a javax.Session with the our properties
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        // From: is our service
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // To: destination given
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Comfirm your account");
        // Instead of simple text, a .html template should be added here!
        message.setText("Welcome....... ");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, port, serviceUsername, servicePassword);
        Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

I dont know why it keeps saying that the password is not specified? Does the SSLSocketFactory have something to do with it? Do i need to call the getPasswordAuthenticion() method somewhere, or calling the second method from my managed bean is all i need?

Comment: Are you using an application server like GlassFish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why your code isn't working, but you might want to take a look at this:

http://spitballer.blogspot.com/2010/02/sending-email-via-glassfish-v3.html

It shows an alternate method of configuring email in Java EE, which I think works much better. The connection details are configured at the container level, just like a container-managed database connection.

Comment: Seconded. That's what I had in mind when I asked about an application server. This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This was a great answer :) I did it in just 10 mins now my app is sending emails ussing a gmail account, wow i am surprised how easy it was :) I love glassfish hehe... Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on SPF and DKIM.

It's hard to know what's going wrong here, as your code is only 1/2 the needed information.  The real issue is probably that your code doesn't fit your environment, and SPF and DKIM often is a reason that connecting to any public SMTP server and sending an email doesn't work.

At least after reading a little about SPF and DKIM, you'll be able to know if it is an issue in your case, or if it is not an issue in your case.